# How to search a string in inner array using mongodb?

Tags: php, mongodb

How to search value in multidimensional array,
for example I want to search `example` keyword in the following data in mongodb
I used to fetch all data from command

`>db.info.find()`

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("4f74737cc3a51043d26f4b90"),
    "id" : "12345",
    "info" : [
            {
                    "sno" : 1,
                    "name" : "ABC",
                    "email" : "abc@example.com"
            },
            {
                    "sno" : 2,
                    "name" : "XYZ",
                    "email" : "xyz@example.com"
            },
            {
                    "sno" : 3,
                    "name" : "XYZ",
                    "email" : "xyz@demo.com"
            },
            {
                    "sno" : 4,
                    "name" : "ABC",
                    "email" : "abc@demo.com"
            },
            {
                    "sno" : 5,
                    "name" : "Rohan",
                    "email" : "rohan@example.com"
            }
    ]
}
```

Now, to find data having `example` I used command

`>db.info.find({"info.email":"example"})`
and it gives

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("4f74737cc3a51043d26f4b90"),
    "id" : "12345",
    "info" : [
            {
                    "sno" : 1,
                    "name" : "ABC",
                    "email" : "abc@example.com"
            },
            {
                    "sno" : 2,
                    "name" : "XYZ",
                    "email" : "xyz@example.com"
            },
            {
                    "sno" : 3,
                    "name" : "XYZ",
                    "email" : "xyz@demo.com"
            },
            {
                    "sno" : 4,
                    "name" : "ABC",
                    "email" : "abc@demo.com"
            },
            {
                    "sno" : 5,
                    "name" : "Rohan",
                    "email" : "rohan@example.com"
            }
    ]
}
```

But I want only 3 out of 5 sub rows like

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("4f74737cc3a51043d26f4b90"),
    "id" : "12345",
    "info" : [
            {
                    "sno" : 1,
                    "name" : "ABC",
                    "email" : "abc@example.com"
            },
            {
                    "sno" : 2,
                    "name" : "XYZ",
                    "email" : "xyz@example.com"
            },
            {
                    "sno" : 5,
                    "name" : "Rohan",
                    "email" : "rohan@example.com"
            }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried Map Reduce Function and it works on this type of problems the code is something like that:

Write a map function

```
  map=function () 
  {
      filter = [];
      this.info.forEach(function (s) {if (/example/.test(s.email)) {filter.push(s);}});
      emit(this._id, {info:filter});
  }
```

Write a reduce function

```
  reduce=function(key, values) { return values;}
```

MapReduce Function

```
  res=db.info.mapReduce(map,reduce,{out:{inline:1}})
```

And The Output look likes:

```
"results" : [
    {
            "_id" : ObjectId("4f9a2de0ea4a65c3ab85a9d3"),
            "value" : {
                    "info" : [
                            {
                                    "sno" : 1,
                                    "name" : "ABC",
                                    "email" : "abc@example.com"
                            },
                            {
                                    "sno" : 2,
                                    "name" : "XYZ",
                                    "email" : "xyz@example.com"
                            },
                            {
                                    "sno" : 5,
                                    "name" : "Rohan",
                                    "email" : "rohan@example.com"
                            }
                    ]
            }
    }
    ],
    "timeMillis" : 1,
    "counts" : {
            "input" : 3,
            "emit" : 3,
            "reduce" : 0,
            "output" : 3
    },
    "ok" : 1,
```

Now you can find your search data from

```
   printjson(res.results)
```

Answer (score 2):

Rohan, MongoDB always returns the *whole* document that you are searching on. You can't just make it return the array elements in which your keyword was found. If you want to do that, then you need to make sure all all embedded documents in the "info" field are in their own collection. And that might mean that you need to link them back to the original document in your "info" collection. Perhaps something like:

```
{
    "sno" : 1,
    "name" : "ABC",
    "email" : "abc@example.com"
    "info_id" : "12345",
},
```

Alternatively, you can of course do post-processing in PHP to obtain only the rows that you want.

Comment: Derick can we say it is a drawback of mongodb?

Comment: It's something that MongoDB wasn't designed for. You need to be aware though that your map reduce solution will have totally different performance characteristics and might end up being a lot worse when you're doing this concurrently. I would still advice it to do in the client.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this is a good idea?
http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongoregex.php

Comment: It will give whole document not the searched inner array data.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try $ (projection)?

```
db.info.find({"info.email":"example"}, {"info.email.$":1})
```

[document](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/#proj._S_)