# How to get a specific object from array of objects inside specific MongoDB document?

Tags: php, mongodb

There is struct of my MongoDB documents:

```js
{
    _id : "12345",
    name : "foo",
    object : {
        array_of_objects : [{
            id : 507,
            name : "some name",
            dt : "2012-06-27 16:35:50"
        },{
            id : 506
            name : "some other name",
            dt : "2012-06-21 16:09:05"
        },
        …
        ]
    }
}
```

I need to get an object from **array_of_objects** with a certain id of the document with the specified **name**. I use php and tried to execute the next code:

```php
$collection->find(array('name' => 'foo', 'object.array_of_objects.id' => 507));
```

It returns all elements of **array_of_objects** instead of element with **id** 507.
After that I try to make query with $elemMatch:

```php
$collection->find(array('name' => 'foo', 'object.array_of_objects' => array('$elemMatch' => array('id' => 507))));
```

But it had return the same. :(
My MongoDB version 2.0.6. Please help.

Comment: Drawback of MongoDB:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10042097/how-to-search-data-in-inner-array-in-mongodb

Comment: @david-cheung thanks! So, I'll try to do this with Mapreduce.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue has been resolved and will be available in MongoDB version 2.2, the next stable release: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-828

I just tried it using MongoDB 2.1.2 (unstable, development release):

sample doc:

```
{ "_id" : 1, "object" : { "array" : [ { "id" : 507, "name" : "Jenna" }, { "id" : 506, "name" : "Matt" } ] } }
```

query:

```
db.food.find({_id:1, "object.array.id":506},{_id:0, "object.array.$":1})
```

result:

```
{ "object" : { "array" : [ { "id" : 506, "name" : "Matt" } ] } }
```

Comment: Good news everyone! 8) Thanks, @Jenna!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this with MongoDB: MongoDB won't drill down into a particular document to extract an item from an array for instance, you have to do this by yourself.

Now the PHP driver might do more work, I don't know -- I'm speaking about MongoDB core queries.

Comment: You can return a subset of fields- check out the MongoDB documentation: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Retrieving+a+Subset+of+Fields

Comment: @Jenna yes you're right -- but a specific item from an array based on its value ?

Comment: As I understand, it can be done either by getting the entire array of objects and the search for the desired item using PHP, or by using MapReduce, right?

Answer (score 0):

So, I did it with MapReduce. Hopefully, this will save someone time and nerves.

```php
$name = 'foo';
$id = 507;

$mongo = new Mongo('…');

$db = $mongo->my_db;

$map = new MongoCode('function(){'.
    'this.object.array_of_objects.forEach(function(obj){'.
        'if (obj.id == '.$id.')'.
            'emit(1, obj);'.
    '});}'
);

$reduce = new MongoCode('function(k,v){ return [k,v]; }');

$response = $db->command(array(
    'mapreduce' => 'my_collection', 
    'map' => $map,
    'reduce' => $reduce,
    'query' => array('name' => $name),
    'out' => array('inline' => 1)
));

var_dump($response['result']);
```